# How to get the stackoverflow questions body using stacky

Tags: stacky

I'm using StackOverflow API on .Net Stacky to try to get the information about the questions with specific tags.
Below is the a sample code

```
var client = new StackyClient("1.1", "", Sites.StackOverflow, new UrlClient(), new JsonProtocol());
var questions = client.GetQuestions(tags: new[] { "odata" }, page:1);
var q = questions.First();
```

Now I got the first question q. The q.Title and other properties of q is correct, but when I try to get the body of q using q.Body, I got NULL. How to get the question body using .Net Stacky?

Answer (score 0):

Seems cannot get the question body using GetQuestions. Here I found the wourk-around

```
var q = client.GetQuestion(questionId, includeBody: true);
```